# How to do word representation of amount field in Acumatica Invoice Report (AR.64.10.00)?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

How to do word representation of amount field in Acumatica Invoice Report (AR.64.10.00)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an un-bound field in DAC Extension for `ARInvoice` DAC. And use `PX.Objects.AP.ToWords` attribute.

```
public class ARInvoicePXExt : PXCacheExtension<ARInvoice>
{
    #region UsrAmountToWords

    public abstract class usrAmountToWords : IBqlField { }


   [PX.Objects.AP.ToWords(typeof(ARInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt))]
    public virtual string UsrAmountToWords { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Use `UsrAmountToWords` field in AR.64.10.00 report.

[image]

[image]

The word representation happens through attribute `PX.Objects.AP.ToWords`. And this out-of-box word representation is English only. For non-English word representation, create your own attribute. Implementation of `PX.Objects.AP.ToWords` can be found in 
…\App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Objects\AP\Descriptor\Attribute.cs.