# Number To Word in Report Design

Tags: acumatica

I see recommend to convert number to word in acumatica in this link [How to do word representation of amount field in Acumatica Invoice Report (AR.64.10.00)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320680/how-to-do-word-representation-of-amount-field-in-acumatica-invoice-report-ar-64) but I follow the instruction, I cannot reach the result. If anyone has idea,please suggest me.

Comment: Can you share your DAC code, report code, as well as screenshots of what the current results are?

Comment: Can you share the code, or any other screenshots on where you have stopped?

Comment: [PXString(250)]
[PX.Objects.AP.ToWords(typeof(ARPayment.curyOrigDocAmt))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="AmountToWords")]